# How to deploy on a remote machine using hudson's WAS Builder Plugin?

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I have a hudson build server (Windows) that does not have Websphere installed. I created a Hudson node that I connect to via SSH. I also installed the WAS Builder Plugin to run jython scripts on the AIX machine. The job that uses the WAS Builder Plugin is tied to the AIX box.

I run into errors. Does anybody know, whether that setup might work or if a different setup will work for the WAS Builder Plugin?

**EDIT:**

I get following Error Message:

```
[test] $ cmd /c call /tmp/hudson9035964108103168395.bat
FATAL: command execution failed

java.io.IOException: cmd: not found
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.fullPath(UNIXProcess.java:372)
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:178)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:114)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:466)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:149)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:121)
 at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:633)
 at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:268)
 at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:778)
 at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:754)
 at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
 at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
 at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:432)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:284)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:665)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:690)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:810)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am wondering whether that plugin can be executed on a slave, especially in my case where the master is on Windows and the slave on AIX.

Comment: The setup sounds OK, but you need to be more specific about the errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it to work. I upgraded the plugin to Version 1.4 and to the newest Hudson server 1.355. That seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Check Here [Hudson Deploy Websphere Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Deploy+WebSphere+Plugin)

Comment: This new plugin looks promising. It currently does'nt support security and WAS 7. Also, we are sometimes using extension packs. Not sure if that will work. We need support for WESB and WPS, which might be supported if the underlying WAS version is supported. I am also not sure if all my needs are satisfied with this plugin, since we also need to uninstall the previous version, replicate with servers (it is actually a WAS ND with Depoloyment Manager) and we also might need to initiate a restart of the WAS. Currently all of that can be achieved to python scripts.

Comment: fair enough... about was 7 I still need to test but i am pretty much confident it works on it. I am currently working on the next release that will cover the security as long as portal server. so if interested stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you remotely trigger builds on Hudson via the hudsonurl:8080/jobs/jobname/build?token=TOKEN url. That way you dont have to depend on BAT files.

Comment: I don't have a problem with triggering a build in Hudson. I wanted to use the WAS builder plugin for security reasons (the password does not need to be configured as a script). Unfortunatly, the Hudson Master runs on Windows and on the target machine (AIX) runs a hudson slave. We don't intend have a full Hudson installation on AIX. I am not sure if the plugin runs on AIX in general or just does not support slaves or if I configured something wrong.